# Postgres. Have to user public.user to query users

Tags: postgresql

I'm using postgres on heroku with a node app. 
I'm connecting to my database no problem and I can query all my other tables no problem
`select * from org;` works perfectly. 
My problem is querying users which are obviously called `user` 
`select * from user` seems to be returning the postgres database user name.
If I use `select * from public.user` I get the list of users I've created. 
Is there a way of just using `user`?
I'm sure I've missed something simple.

Answer (score 2):

[`USER`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html) is a reserved word in SQL Standard, thus it also is in PostgreSQL.

You should **NOT** use that as your table name.

Type  `select user` to see that it will also give you the name of user that holds current conection to the database.

As to your question, there is no way of using just `user` as a reference to your table.

From documentation, **bold emphasis mine**:

> SQL distinguishes between reserved and non-reserved key words. According to the standard, **reserved key words** are the only real key words; **they are never allowed as identifiers**. Non-reserved key words only have a special meaning in particular contexts and can be used as identifiers in other contexts.

Comment: Keywords _can_ be used if quoted: `select * fom "user"` would work

Comment: Anyways, did I say that a word `user` can't be quoted? It might be late, but I'm not seeing it in my answer.